# iOS File won't write to directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm using cocoaHTTPServer library that allows you to store files "publicly".  For some reason I can't write files to the directory.

I can write to my local file directory, but not the public "Web" folder.

```
/var/mobile/Applications/42CE308A-F804-47E3-BA07-CB921B909FFB/Documents/song.caf
/var/mobile/Applications/42CE308A-F804-47E3-BA07-CB921B909FFB/MyApp.app/Web/song.caf
```

The top one works, the bottom one doesn't.
Meaning, when I save the file, then check for the file in the documents directory, it is there, when I save, and then check the "Web" directory, the directory is empty.

And i'm using AVAssetWriter to save the song.

```
NSString *exportPath = [DataCenter sharedDataCenter].songURLLocal;


if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportPath error:nil];
}
NSURL *exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];
AVAssetWriter *assetWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:exportURL
                                                       fileType:AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat
                                                          error:&assetError];
```

Comment: @JasonCoco for having such amount of reputation on here, you should know better than to leave such a comment, which is neither helpful or constructive.

Comment: @spentak What is the **`assetError`** output? Try `NSLog(@"Asset Error: %@",[assetError localizedDescription]);`

Comment: @WrightsCS The comment is not constructive to the problem, which is why it's left as a comment and not an answer. It has a winkle to show it's meant to be playful, and I believe this community should be a serious development community but that there's nothing wrong with light-hearted or playful comments. If I had an answer for him, I'd have given it. I personally don't believe there's anything wrong with this type of comment and I believe very strongly that comments like this from me and from others add to the community as a whole.

Comment: @WrightsCS I take back my previous comment... this question was __completely different__ when I read it and commented on it. I wouldn't have left that comment on this question as it doesn't even make sense. Please see the edit history...

Comment: @JasonCoco if this kind of commenting was accepted on S.O., then there wouldn't be a little flag with the **not constructive / off-topic** option. Also, developers don't come here for humor, thats what Facebook is for. People come here to accomplish their goal of resolving an issue and to complete their project.

Comment: @spentak Please don't edit a question to make it completely different. If you have a new question, please create a new question. Otherwise it can be very confusing.

Comment: Sorry, Stack limited my posts for the day :p

Answer (score 0):

What does the `assetError` output through `NSLog`?

Also, You will not be able to write the the **Web** directory which is clearly located in your app bundle — which is sandboxed. The only directory you can write to is the **Documents** directory.

Also, what is the **`NSString *exportPath = [DataCenter sharedDataCenter].songURLLocal`**?

If `exportPath` is the **Web** directory then your methods will always fail.

Comment: It is the Web directory.  How do I save files dynamically then to a public location so others can access them through a link such as http://myipAddress:12345/song.caf

Comment: The only directory you should be suing for this purpose is the **Documents** directory, which is write-enabled to your application. The **Library** directory, which is created by the app bundle when installed, is also write-enabled, but I wouldn't recommend using this directory for sharing.